# fail to submit form in JSP

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I use a Bootstrap2 module to make a web APP. But I failed to submit the form. I hava set attributes.("method" and "action"), and I also tried to write the target link in label , it didn't work. Here is my HTML:

```
<form id="financial_update_form" method="POST" action="financial_update_do.jsp" class="form-horizontal">
...
...
</form>
<a href="" id="financial_update_sure_btn" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="icon-plus icon-white"></i> submit</a>
<a href="financial_management.jsp" id="financial_update_cancle_btn" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="icon-plus icon-white"></i> back</a>
```

I use js to control it, js code is as below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var form = document.getElementById("financial_update_form");
var sure = document.getElementById("financial_update_sure_btn");
var cancle = document.getElementById("financial_update_cancle_btn");
sure.onclick = function(){
form.submit();
};
</script>
```

I think it should have worked.
get the form by it's id, and then when the surn botton is clicked, submit the form. Why am I wrong?...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hava found how to solve it.
It has been proved that js can be used in submitting a form, even if  tag is beyond the . By following that:

1. set the 's "method" and "action" attribute, it is important
2. change the 's attribute "href" from certain link to "javascript:functionname()",like:
3. and write your own javascript, like:

   var form = document.getElementById("note_new_form");
       var btn = document.getElementById("note_new_form_btn");
       btn.onclick = function submitform(){
           form.submit();
       };

It worked.

Answer (score 0):

As soon as the JavaScript fires, the link (to the current page) is followed and the form submission is canceled.

Forget the JavaScript. If you want to submit a form, use a submit button.

```
<form id="financial_update_form" method="POST" action="financial_update_do.jsp" class="form-horizontal">
  ...
  ...
  <button id="financial_update_sure_btn" class="btn btn-primary">
    <i class="icon-plus icon-white"></i>
    submit
  </button>
</form>
```

Comment: but I succeeded in another JSP, it is vary similar.The script is as:`var form = document.getElementById("financial_new_form"); var btn = document.getElementById("financial_new_form_btn"); btn.onclick = function(){if(type.value !='please choose' && amount.value !=''){form.submit();}`